# Connection issue between MongoDB and Mongo express in docker on the same host

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoexport

i am facing Connection issue between MongoDB and Mongo express both the containers are on the same host which a Compute instance with ubuntu image.

Docker Commands used to build the containers:

```
sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 -d -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb --net mongo-network mongo

sudo docker run -d -p 8082:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb mongo-express
```

```
Error logs from the mongo express container:
 Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.19.0.2:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I understand mongo express is not able to establish connection to mongo DB

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63cbdcc76f21488dfa6416fa
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.1
Using MongoDB:      6.0.3
Using Mongosh:      1.6.1`
```

I though the port was blocked by firewall but it not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the container network part. So you should create a docker network.

```
docker network create mongo-network
```

Then attach your existing containers to this network

```
docker network connect mongo-network mongodb
docker network connect mongo-network mongo-express
```